# Arduino create dec out of HEX

Tags: arduino

I want to write an hex number in the serial monitor and this should be convert to a decimal int.

```
LCDShield lcd;
byte byteR;
int color = 0;

if (Serial.available()) {
    int number;
    byteR = Serial.read();

    if (byteR >= 'A') {
        number = byteR - 55;
    } else {
        number = byteR - '0';
    }
    color = (color * 16) + number;
    Serial.print(color, HEX);
    Serial.write('\n');
}
```

Why is that not working? If I write `FFFFFF` it shows:

```
F
FF
FFF
FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF
```

Comment: Please show more code, this seems to be the inner part of some loop.

Comment: What's `55`????

Comment: Try unsigned int for variable color.

Comment: colour = (0 * 16) + ('F' - 55) which is nothing but colour = 0+ (70 -55) and 15 in HEX is F. that's why you are getting ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you declared `color` as `int`, but `int` has only `2` bytes on **Arduino** and you are trying to store `3` bytes in it.

You see `4` bytes on *serial* because `print()` promotes an `int` to `long` before printing it out. Since after you stored `2` full bytes in your `int` variable this contains a *negative* value (`0xFFFF` is a negative int), the promotion to long extends the whole number with more 'F' as per *Two's complement* [prescriptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement), thus getting `0xFFFFFFFF`.

The solution is to declare `color` of type `unsigned long`.

---

You should do this:

```cpp
unsigned long color = 0;
boolean ignore_in = false;
boolean in_done = false;

...

if (Serial.available()) {
    ignore_in = false;
    byte c = Serial.read();
    byte in;

    if('A' <= c && c <= 'F') {
        in = c - 'A' + 10;
    } else if ('a' <= c && c <= 'f') {
        in = c - 'a' + 10;
    } else if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') {
        in = c - '0';
    } else if (c == '\n' ) {
        in_done = true;
        ignore_in = true;
    } else {
        // print error: unrecognized character [?]
        ignore_in = true;
    }

    if (!ignore_in) {
        color = (color << 4) | in;

        Serial.print(color, HEX);
        Serial.write('\n');
    }
}

if (in_done) {
    // do something with color

    ...

    // reset
    color = 0;
    in_done = false;
}

...
```

Comment: If integers are only 2 bytes, how would you explain the output is F, then FF, then FFF and finally FFFFFFFF? Moreover, your shift left of 16 bits seems incorrect.

Comment: @linuxfan I edited my answer with an explanation in the header, and I replaced the shift with the exact same mathematics used by the OP. :)

Comment: It's working. Thank you! But by the way: I found a better way! I just took the Serial.print, and moved it *after* the }. But thanks!